# EOMONTH() alternative in BETWEEN statement for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a way to replace EOMONTH in PostgreSQL.  I have a db with a date column.  I have a script I want to run on the first of the month that will select only the rows that fall between last months first day and last day.

I need the equivalent of this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM database 
WHERE dateCol BETWEEN SYMMETRIC EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)+1 AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1);
```

I am very new to SQL, so let me know if something doesn't make sense.  Thank you!

Comment: What exactly does `EOMONTH()` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Last day of month of first argument. If second argument present, first add that number of month to the first argument and then calculate end of month

Comment: I woul have a look at the ```date_trunc()``` function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL Server expression:

```
EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)+1
```

Means: last day of month M-2 (we are in November, so this means September 30th)

One way to express this in postgres is:

```
date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
```

Which means: truncate the current date to the first day of the month, then go back 1 month and one day.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9614b51dbdf948eae6fa7e8608e3a370)**

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @NMALM! Glad that it helped out.